# unzip -d option to extract file from jar to specific directory

Tags: linux, shell, unix, jar, unzip

unzip -d option to extract file from jar to specific directory

Without using any option we can unzip specific file to same directory structure, but -d option doesn't seem to work.

```
unzip someNiceOne.jar com/some/comp/some/dir/name.properties
```

This will unzip file 'name.properties' to 'com/some/comp/some/dir/'.

I need 'name.properties' to be under same directory level where my jar is present, but -d option doesn't seem to work. Any alternative option?.

> unzip -d option help :
>
> -d  extract files into exdir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `-j` option should do what you need.

```
-j  junk paths (do not make directories)
```

In your case:

```
unzip -j someNiceOne.jar com/some/comp/some/dir/name.properties
```